# Discord.js - Storing N amount of command arguments into an array

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to write a command that I don't know how many arguments will have and then store all those arguments inside an array. It will work like that:

-User says !test 123 321 444 589

-The bot will store 123 321 444 589

-Another user says !test 2 22

-The bot will store 2 22

Right now my code is like this and it works fine with 1 argument.

```
client.on("message", message => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  const array = [];

  if (command === "test") {
    array.push(args[0]);
  }
}
```

How would I implement this?

Comment: `array.push(args[0]);` you're only pushing the first element, you can probably just do `array.push(...args);` to get all the arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `args` variable is already your array of arguments. To copy it, you can do this:

```
const array = args;
```

To move all the elements of one array into an *existing* array, use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), like so:

```
array.push(...args);
```